# how can i add two int values in the xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

how can i add two int values in the XSLT, my field max length is 5, as of now how i am doing please find code below pasted

Assume Rowcount value as **7**

```
<xsl:param name ="Rowcount"/>

<xsl:variable name ="value1">
<xsl:value-of select ="00000"/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:value-of select ="$Value1 + $Rowcount"/>
```

output showing as 7

But Output Required is **00007**

kindly advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

0000 plus 7 results in the Value 7, thats mathematical correct, what you want is a formatted Number or String.

You could use the function `string format-number(number, string, string?)`

The first Parameter of `format-number(7, "00000")` is your input number, the second is the formatpattern. The third Paramter is optional, a name of a format.

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number($Rowcount, $value1)"/>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/func_formatnumber.asp

Comment: Care to comment your code? How does it works? How does it answers OP question?

Answer (score -1):

If i remember correctly you could try to make value1 be treated as a string like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select ="$Value1 + '' + $Rowcount"/>
```

for a more complex formatting of numbers have a look at:

http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/func_formatnumber.asp